# How should I paint my basement floor?

Tags: concrete, painting, floor, caulking

I have an 80 year old basement concrete floor that recent had asbestos tiles and mastic removed. It is in good shape, with a few hairline cracks.  I  am planning on painting it. The basement is dry, but humid in the summer. I will use it as a laundry room/crafting/doing projects on the work bench. I see that a good bonding primer is recommended.

My questions are:

- I am on the fence as to whether I should use an epoxy paint or a porch and floor enamel(or another enamel type) paint.  I want the paint job to last many years!
- Should I put a concrete sealer wet look to help seal the paint? Whatever I put down, I want it easy to mop.
- There is about 1/4 space between the concrete floor and the concrete wall, should I seal this with something before painting?  Is is better to leave it open to give the floor a chance to "breath" If it better to seal it up,  what product is best for caulking concrete?

Answer (score 1):

A **true two-part epoxy** will be the most **durable** option, yet the priciest. The active mixing agent, causes the coat of paint to dry extremely hard and durable. Valspar offers a great product that is available in a variety of colors. Valspar also has a clear epoxy coat to add extra protection to the floor coating and adds a glossy shine.

[Valspar Garage Floor Coating](http://www.valsparpaint.com/en/find-the-right-product/concrete/garage-floor-coat.html)

A cheaper route, and **lesser in quality** is using Seal-Krete's Concrete & Garage Floor Paint. It is labeled as an epoxy, but it is not a true epoxy since there is no mixing agent. However, the paint does dry hard for protection. Seal-Krete also offers 
Clear-Seal for a clear topcoat.

[Seal-Krete Concrete & Garage Floor Paint](http://www.sealkrete.com/find-a-product/find-a-product/concrete-paints/)

Either choice requires proper surface preparation. The concrete should be cleaned, etched and dry of moisture. Both Valspar and Seal-Krete sell concrete surface prep solutuions.

Answer (score 0):

The epoxy paints are not really an epoxy.  A real epoxy would have an activating ingredient.  This designation is fake marketing.  I do suggest you get a paint that is suitable for garage floor installation.  The problem with painting a basement floor is the ease of scratching because usually you have metal storage things.

Yes to #2 because constant mopping will wear down the paint bonding.

3 is really a different question.  Sealing this is outside of your paint project.  We would have to have more info for this.